# Who was W.I.E. Gates?

Tags: references

According to, e.g., [this link](http://www.quotehd.com/quotes/author/w-i-e-gates-quotes), he is the author of the quote

> Then there is the man who drowned while crossing a stream that was, on
>   average, 6 inches deep.

The quote is to illustrate that location measures like the mean ought to be complemented with dispersion measures like the standard deviation.

My question: who was (is?) W.I.E. Gates? My search only reveals his name in the context of this quote.

Comment: Since he's using inches, he supposedly comes from the US.

Comment: People named William often use or answer to the nickname Bill, as in William Jefferson Clinton, ex-President of the US, is commonly referred to as Bill Clinton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I.E. Gates was a Baptist leader in Texas in the twentieth century. He was a popular preacher and led a Baptist college. Look for his book, Watching the World Go By. It's a fun book where Gates tells about his life.

Comment: This appears to answer the question but why was it even asked here?

Comment: @MichaelChernick: like others before me, I wanted to include the quote in slides of mine, and when giving a reference, want to have at least a rough idea whom I'm quoting.

Comment: I understand why you asked the question but I don't yet understand how it pertains to the topics discussed on this site.